# Google Transaction in German leads to "Sorry, I didn't get any response."

Tags: actions-on-google

I created a pure German example of https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs .
When I trigger the action via phone (or web Simulator) and go into the first step "transaction_check_nopayment" I see in the logs that the method is called but in the client I get as response: "Sorry, I didn't get any response."
What could be the problem? how to get closer to the problem?

Here is the log:

```
2018-01-08T08:03:20.685Z I transactions: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 08:03:20 GMT actions-on-google:debug checkForTransactionRequirements: transactionConfig=undefined, dialogState=undefined
2018-01-08T08:03:20.685Z I transactions: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 08:03:20 GMT actions-on-google:debug fulfillSystemIntent_: intent=actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK, specType=type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.TransactionRequirementsCheckSpec, intentSpec={}, promptPlaceholder=PLACEHOLDER_FOR_TXN_REQUIREMENTS dialogState=undefined
2018-01-08T08:03:20.685Z I transactions: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 08:03:20 GMT actions-on-google:debug buildResponse_: textToSpeech=PLACEHOLDER_FOR_TXN_REQUIREMENTS, expectUserResponse=true, noInputs=undefined
2018-01-08T08:03:20.686Z I transactions: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 08:03:20 GMT actions-on-google:debug isSsml_: text=PLACEHOLDER_FOR_TXN_REQUIREMENTS
2018-01-08T08:03:20.690Z I transactions: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 08:03:20 GMT actions-on-google:debug getUser
2018-01-08T08:03:20.691Z I transactions: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 08:03:20 GMT actions-on-google:debug doResponse_: response={"speech":"PLACEHOLDER_FOR_TXN_REQUIREMENTS","contextOut":[{"name":"_actions_on_google_","lifespan":100,"parameters":{}}],"data":{"google":{"expectUserResponse":true,"noInputPrompts":[],"isSsml":false,"systemIntent":{"intent":"actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK","data":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.TransactionRequirementsCheckSpec"}}}}}, responseCode=200
2018-01-08T08:03:20.691Z I transactions: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 08:03:20 GMT actions-on-google:debug isNotApiVersionOne_
2018-01-08T08:03:20.691Z I transactions: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 08:03:20 GMT actions-on-google:debug Response {"speech":"PLACEHOLDER_FOR_TXN_REQUIREMENTS","contextOut":[{"name":"_actions_on_google_","lifespan":100,"parameters":{}}],"data":{"google":{"expectUserResponse":true,"noInputPrompts":[],"isSsml":false,"systemIntent":{"intent":"actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK","data":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.TransactionRequirementsCheckSpec"}}}}}
2018-01-08T08:03:20.693712230Z D transactions: Function execution took 627 ms, finished with status code: 200
2018-01-08T08:03:20.698Z I transactions: Mon, 08 Jan 2018 08:03:20 GMT actions-on-google:debug undefined
```

When I compare the logs for the working English version and the not working German version for this step I see a difference: 
In the English log every lines ends with "transactions hyd4scvzft31". This part I miss in the German logs. 
However in the configuration of my German app I also answered "Does your app perform Transactions?" with YES.

In the example on transaction_check_nopayment app.askForTransactionRequirements() is called. May be askForTransactionRequirements() is not supported in German? Is there an overview of the transaction-API documenting the supported languages? Should the transaction API work for a German use case? As payment method I have invoice. When I understand the documentation this is like having no payment in the google-API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden under `Policies and Terms > Other > Special Requirements for Certain Use Cases`, Google states 'Currently, the Transactions API is only available in the United States; apps in other countries cannot implement the API or complete transactions until the API is available there.'

[Source](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#transactions)